# Flutter UI update failure with Riverpod StateNotifierProvider

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, riverpod

I am building a simple calculator and using Riverpod for state management. Though I can update state, the UI is not being updated with the changes... Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong ??   Here's the code:

Calculator Model

```
class CalculatorModel {
  final bool shouldAppend;
  final String equation;
  final String result;

  const CalculatorModel(
      {this.shouldAppend = true, this.equation = '0', this.result = '0'});

  CalculatorModel copyWith({
    bool? shouldAppend,
    String? equation,
    String? result,
  }) =>
      CalculatorModel(
          shouldAppend: shouldAppend ?? this.shouldAppend,
          equation: equation ?? this.equation,
          result: result ?? this.result);
}
```

Calculator State Notifier Implementation

```
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:components/calculator_components/calculator_model.dart';
import 'package:math_expressions/math_expressions.dart';

final calculatorProvider =
    StateNotifierProvider<CalculatorStateNotifier, List<CalculatorModel>>(
        (ref) => CalculatorStateNotifier());

class CalculatorStateNotifier extends StateNotifier<List<CalculatorModel>> {
  CalculatorStateNotifier() : super([const CalculatorModel()]);

  void append(String calcInput) {
    final equation = () {
      return state[0].equation == '0'
          ? calcInput
          : state[0].equation + calcInput;
    }();

    state[0] = CalculatorModel(equation: equation);
  }
}
```

Click function for calculator buttons. State is getting updated, successfully...

```
void onClickedButton(String calcInput, WidgetRef ref) {
  ref.read(calculatorProvider.notifier).append(calcInput);
  ref.watch(calculatorProvider);
  print(ref.watch(calculatorProvider)[0].equation);
}
```

Riverpod not updating UI when called in the presentation layer...

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    return Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 5),
      margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
      width: size.width * 0.8,
            child: Column(children: [
        Expanded(
          child: Container(
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.0, right: 22),
                child: Consumer(builder: (context, ref, _) {
                  return buildCalculatorScreen(
                      ref.watch(calculatorProvider)[0].equation,
                      ref.watch(calculatorProvider)[0].result);
                }),
              )),
        ),
        
      ]),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you should not use `ref.watch` on asynchronous calls, including button calls.
Second, Since our state is immutable, we are not allowed to do `state[0] =` . You need to update your List in some other way, such as using the spread operator or `List.of()`

More information here:
[StateNotifierProvider from Riverpod](https://riverpod.dev/docs/providers/state_notifier_provider)

Comment: First, you should not use ref.watch on asynchronous calls, including button calls. - What can I use then?? Should it be `ref.read` ? "...You need to update your List in some other way, such as using the spread operator or `List.of()`..." - Please could you provide me an example... because I tried various other methods and I just kept getting errors.

Comment: The link I provided above has great examples of how to work with `Lists`. And in callbacks you should use `ref.read` ^)

Answer (score 0):

`state` should be immutable, you have to set a new object/array as the new state.
You can do something like this:

```
final newState = List.from(state);
newState[0] = CalculatorModel(equation: equation);
state = newState;
```